# cURL php in live server Amazon Web Service not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, libcurl

### I don't know what's the problem with this. But my curl doesn't work. I tried everything research everywhere and my last option is this, I tried to remove all my code and remain only this

```
echo "before curl";
$curl_handle=curl_init();
echo "after curl";

Then my output is only 
"before curl", so therefore there's a problem with my curl and not other codes.
Someone help me. I deployed it on Amazon Web Service.

Is it possible that it doesn't accept request from CURL? or do I need to install any library?
CURL is working on my local.
```

Comment: Surely, you need to add curl to PHP in your AWS server. You can do a phpinfo() an see if curl is there or not.

Comment: I checked my phpinfo but all I can see in cURL is this.

"cURL     |        Sterling Hughes"

Comment: Can you give me instruction how to add cURL in my PHP?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with AWS. I kwon how to do it in xampp, cpanel/whm, no more.

Comment: anyway thankyou for this @JoséCarlosPHP. I just figure out that cURL is not installed on my server. I installed it and it works now. Thanks